# Bacula Postgresql Huge Logs table

Tags: linux, postgresql, bacula

We currently have Bacula Enterprise v12 installed on our production.

We seem to have a problem with BWEB regarding the logs of any job. it takes forever for the web interface to load the logs.

After some doing some manual queries to the database we discovered that it takes a very long time to load the queries ,and also that the two biggest tables on the database are the file and logs tables about 500 gigs each.

We are wondering we these table are so large se bacula should be pruning them at 3 months ,based on our configuration.

I will be happy to provide any .conf files for postgres , Director and consoles , bweb, etc. .. if requested.

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Comment: *"bacula should be pruning them at 3 months"* - As a basic concept: a time based retention policy does not actually impose a limit to the size/number of data points (you can generate a lot of data over a 3 month period)

Comment: Bacula is under constantly improvement. Do you have an anual or perpetual license ?
I suggest you to upgrade your Bacula Enterprise version (the current version is 16.0.11)

Comment: we have e perpetual license . But our support has been terminated and thus we cant update to the latest version. We are stuck using 12.8.3.